# Regex not matching in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string:

```
 string error = "<MESSAGES><MESSAGE SEVERITY=\"2\" NUMBER=\"16\" TEXT=\"The Record Case is locked by user\" /></MESSAGES>";
```

I want to match between the  `TEXT=\"` and the following `\`

I'm using the following expression `var regex = new Regex(@"TEXT=\\""(.*?)\\");`

Expresso tells me this regex is correct.
RegExr tells me this regex is correct.

But C# disagrees.

**I've tried**

- `Groups[]` and match.Value.
- `\x22` instead of `"` as I thought it might be an escape problem.
- `/TEXT=\""(.*?)\/g`

All, to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: Useful for this kind of stuff is Linqpad ( https://www.linqpad.net/ ) which basically gives you a C# console you can use to practice on.

Comment: The string doesn't have the backslashes, it's just to escape the quotes. You must not have them in your regexp

Comment: That's XML, can't you just parse it as an XElement and read the `text` attribute `elem.Attribute("text").Value` etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `XElement`, you have an XML fragment:

```
var error = "<MESSAGES><MESSAGE SEVERITY=\"2\" NUMBER=\"16\" TEXT=\"The Record Case is locked by user\" /></MESSAGES>";
var xe = XElement.Parse(error);
var res = xe.Elements("MESSAGE")
                   .Where(p => p.HasAttributes && p.Attributes("TEXT") != null)
                   .Select(n => n.Attribute("TEXT").Value)
                   .ToList();
```

Output:

[image]

Mind that with very large input strings, `.*?` may cause catastrophic backtracking, that is why you should avoid using it whenever possible. If you need a regex for this (because some of your input is not XML-valid), you can use:

```
var attr_vals = Regex.Matches(error, @"(?i)\bTEXT=""([^""]+)""")
             .OfType<Match>()
             .Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)
             .ToList();
```

(2 times faster than Karthik's, tested on regexhero.com)

Output:

[image]

Mind that with regex, you will get all XML entities untouched (e.g. `&amp;` and not `&`). You will have to use [`System.Web.HttpUtility`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) later.

Comment: `2 times faster`... indeed.. +1 :)

Comment: +1 - this is the best implementation by a long shot - although I do feel like I need to mark Phuongs answer as correct.

Comment: Please note that Phuong's solution (that is actually `@"TEXT=""(.*?)"""`) is worse in principle because `(.*?)` lazy matching is less safe compared to negated character class. If you need to match escaped sequences, it is not at all correct, you need to use [`@"\bTEXT=""[^""\\]*(?:\\.[^""\\]*)*"`](https://regex101.com/r/kT8qD6/1) then.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following (your actual string will be compiled to a string without `\`'s.. since you are just using them as escape characters):

```
var regex = new Regex(@"TEXT=""([^""]+)""");
```

Comment: the `(.*?)` should definitely be optimized into something like `([^"*])` to prevent the catastrophic backtracking coming with that matcher. If the value may contain quotation marks a lookbehind expression would be the better option

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Regex.Match(error, "TEXT=\\\"(.*?)\\\"")
```

You need to escape both `\` and `"` character with `\`

Comment: This was the correct answer to my question -"Why is my regex not working" - this made it work - it was an escape error -.-.I am however going with stribizhevs answer as this is a nicer implementation.

Thanks Phuong

Comment: Actually, the regex is the same as `"TEXT=\"(.*?)\""`. You do not have to escape `"` in a .NET regular expression ([see Character Escapes in Regular Expressions reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).